# I can't create migration Laravel5 Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel-5, backend

Terminal show me this message:

[image]

my env:

[image]

my database.php:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'mysql' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravelup'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),            
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1'),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),   
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',    
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',    
  'prefix' => '',  
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => null,        
],
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Please don't use images unless necessary. It's harder to read and impossible to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your .env file like this

```
DB_DATABASE=laravelup
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=                  //blank here
```

And it will be working.

I maybe laravel configration cache problem.

```
If you type this command "php artisan config:clear" and try again, then it will be working.
```

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: selec
  t * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Have you set DB_DATABASE=laravelup? It seems you are still setting this value to homestead

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelup
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Have you leaved DB_PASSWORD as blank? Even space is not allowed.

Comment: I see. Then it should be cache problem. Please try to type this command in the console "php artisan config:clear" and try again.

Comment: php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 7
  67 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 7
  67 bytes

Comment: I don't know what is this but table in my database exist                                           [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 7
  67 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 7
  67 bytes

Comment: Okay. If you solved the problem, please mark my answer as accepted. You can see tick mark on the left side of my answer.